# Lost .netcharting functionality after changing project from .NET 4 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts

I have a project that uses the asp chart control. The project was developed to use .net 4.0 but the server uses version 3.5. I changed the project to 3.5 but now my charts don't work. When I change it it tells me that system.web.DataVisualisation.dll will be removed.

I guess I am looking for a fix which will add this assembly back?

any help most appreciated!

Jonesy

Answer (score 0):

Can you just not add the reference again? (After you deploy the .dll again)

Edit: manual alteration of web.config may be needed. Look for: System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0.

Comment: sorry this may seem stupid but how would i deploy the .dll again?

Comment: I'd personally start a fresh 3.5 project and add charting to it. Make sure the .dll's from that dummy project are deployed to the local bin when you compile. Grab them from there and copy them to your existing downgraded project. Link to these files (add reference in visual studio). Adapt your web.config as required.

Comment: Hi I've tried your suggestion but nothing happens. I'm getting exactly the same error messages. I'm updating my question with my code